# "hadoop namenode -format" formats wrong directory

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop 1.1.2.21 on CentOS 6.3

I've configured dfs.name.dir in /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml file

```
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/mnt/ext/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
```

But when I run "hadoop namenode -format" command, it formats /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name instead.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It might be taking the path `/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name` from `hdfs-default.xml`. Not sure why the value from `hdfs-site.xml` is not taken. Is `dfs.name.dir` marked as `final` in `hdfs-default.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and solved it. So updating this answer.
Make sure your environment variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` points to the directory where it can find all you `xml` files for used for configuration. It solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if some Hadoop Process is running in the background already. This happens if you have aborted a previous process and it has not been killed and has become a **ZOMBIE** process
  If that is the case kill the process and then again try to format the system
- Also you can check the permission of the Directory.
- Try to give a different location for the directory, if it is reflected

Answer (score 0):

Please don't set HADOOP_CONF_DIR. You can check .bashrc file and remove it.